# Initialize a upgradeable contract through a contract

Tags: ethereum, upgrade, solidity, openzeppelin

I want to make a factory contract that can deploy upgradeable children contracts. But then I am confused with who is the actual owner of the proxy contract when I want to upgrade the children contract later.

So if the ownership of the children's contract is transferred to admin, does that mean the ProxyAdmin's ownership is also transferred to admin? If not, how can I successfully upgrade the children's contract?

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract Factory is Ownable {
    event NewChildingContract(address children);
    
    constructor() {}

    function deployChild(
        uint256 _startBlock,
        address _admin
    ) external onlyOwner {
        
        bytes memory bytecode = type(Children).creationCode;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_startBlock));
        address childrenAddress;

        assembly {
            childrenAddress := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }

        Children(childrenAddress).initialize(
            _startBlock,
            _admin
        );

        emit NewChildrenContract(childrenAddress);
    }
}


contract Children is OwnableUpgradeable {
    address public FACTORY;

    
    uint256 public startBlock;

    
    constructor() {
        FACTORY = msg.sender;
    }

    function initialize(
        uint256 _startBlock,
        address _admin
    ) external {
        require(msg.sender == FACTORY, "Not factory");

        
        OwnableUpgradeable.__Ownable_init();
        
        
        startBlock = block.number > _startBlock? block.number : _startBlock;
        
        // Transfer ownership to the admin address who becomes owner of the contract
        transferOwnership(_admin);
    }
}
```